# Microchip RF Modulator issue

Tags: c, microchip, pic32

I'm using a pair of MRF24J40 radio chips to get one PIC32 microcontroller board to communicate with another via RF transmission. I've got all my code to compile fine but I keep getting an error associated with this code.

```
typedef struct
    {
        union
        {
            BYTE        Val;  
            struct
            {
                BYTE    packetType      :2;             // type of packet. Possible types are
                                                        // * PACKET_TYPE_DATA - Data type
                                                        // * PACKET_TYPE_COMMAND -  Command type
                                                        // * PACKET_TYPE_ACK -  Acknowledgement type
                                                        // * PACKET_TYPE_RESERVE - Reserved type
                BYTE    broadcast       :1;             // 1: broadcast, 0: unicast
                BYTE    secEn           :1;             // 1: secure the MAC payload, 0: send plain text
                BYTE    repeat          :1;             // 1: allow repeaters to forward the message, 0: send message directly
                BYTE    ackReq          :1;             // 1: acknowledgement required, 0: no acknowldgement
                BYTE    destPrsnt       :1;             // 1: destination address in the packet, 0: destination address not in the packet
                BYTE    sourcePrsnt     :1;             // 1: source address in the packet, 0: source address not in the packet
            } bits;
        } flags;

        BYTE *      SourceAddress;                      // Address of the Sender
        BYTE *      Payload;                            // Pointer to the payload
        BYTE        PayloadLen;                         // Payload size
        BYTE        RSSIValue;                          // RSSI value for the received packet
        BYTE        LQIValue;                           // LQI value for the received packet
        #if defined(IEEE_802_15_4)
            BOOL        altSourceAddress;               // Source address is the alternative network address
            WORD_VAL    SourcePANID;                    // PAN ID of the sender
        #endif
    } MAC_RECEIVED_PACKET;
```

Basically I've tried everything on earth to be able to change the values of the variables `packetType`, `secEn`, `ackReq` etc. I've tried changing the value directly after their declarations but that seems to be the bit length, not the value. The code (straight from microchip's website) has comments that say 1 = this and 0 = that but I haven't found anywhere where I can change those values. Any help from anyone familiar with these MRF24J40 chips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything specific to do with your microcontroller, it's just that you may not be familiar with how `struct` and `union` are used to define bitfields in C.

`MAC_RECEIVED_PACKET` is a `struct` that has a field called `flags`.  `flags` is a `union` between a `BYTE` and a `struct` bitfield called `bits`.

In the declaration, each field in `bits` is followed by its bit length.  Thus, e.g., packetType, which is 2 bits can take on values 0, 1, 2, 3.  You set the values like this:

```
MAC_RECEIVED_PACKET foo;
foo.flags.bits.packetType = 3;
foo.flags.bits.secEn      = 1;
/* etc. */
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you mean when you say that you've tried to change the values ​​.. 
for example if you want to choose the type of packet and set PACKET_TYPE_ACK -  Acknowledgement type:

```
MAC_RECEIVED_PACKET myrpacket; 

myrpacket.flags.bits.packetType=2;
```

packetType can take this values:

```
00 =0 --> PACKET_TYPE_DATA
01 =1 --> PACKET_TYPE_COMMAND
10 =2 --> PACKET_TYPE_ACK
11 =3 --> PACKET_TYPE_RESERVE
```

why?

bits, is a BYTE data ,and packetType ,are the first 2 bits of this byte, as is declared in the structure:

```
  BYTE    packetType      :2;
```

so if you want setup ackReq

```
  myrpacket.flags.bits.ackReq=1;
```

hope this help you